# Inserting multiple instances of the form into DB in Django

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
def test_view(request, list):

    my_form = MyForm(request.POST)
    for x in list:
        my_instance = my_form.save(commit = false)
        my_instance.variable_field = x['content']
        my_form.save()
```

Now for some reason, new record is inserted into the DB only during the first iteration. My guess is that it has something to do with [form prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms), but I still didn't come across any material in the doc describing how to tackle this situation appropriately.

**UPDATE:**
Just to clarify: I have a form which underlying instance contain a field that I've excluded from the form and turned it into a selectize element in my interface. The user can choose multiple options in the selectize, that's why I need the for-loop in the code extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing this:

```
def test_view(request, list):

   my_form = MyForm(request.POST) 

   for x in list:
        my_instance = my_form.save(commit = false)
        if my_instance.id:
                my_instance.id = None
        my_instance.variable_field = x['content']
        my_form.save()
```

Comment: Well, two comments. First, you don' need the  "if my_instance.id:", second, do you think it's the clearest method to do it ? I will add an update to the question to clarify the issue a bit

Comment: The goal behind this code was that for any item in list there will be an instance saved to the database. The my_instance=None just copies the instance (AFAIK this is still the standard way of copying instances in django)..